# Spring Boot: Adding static resources from file system breaks existing mappings

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot MVC application in which I am trying to load resources from an external folder on the file system. I have used the following to configure this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {  
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/where/**")
          .addResourceLocations("file:///C:/some/where/");  
    }
...
}
```

Once I configure this, I can access my static files by going to `http://serverurl/where/somefile`

BUT, I am no longer able to access the home page at `http://serverurl/`

Any idea what I did wrong here?